# How to use platt scaling with cross-validation using LIBSVM?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, libsvm, cross-validation

Could somebody give me the example to show how platt scaling is used along with k-fold cross-validation in multiclass SVM classification in libsvm?

I have divided the whole dataset in two parts: Training and testing. For cross-validation i am partitioning the training data such that 1 partition is for testing and rest is for training multiclass SVM classifier.

Answer (score 0):

Platt scaling has nothing to do with your partitioning or multiclass setting. Platt scaling is internal technique of each individual binary SVM, which uses only a training data. This is actually just fitting a logistic reggresion on top of your learned SVM projections.

Comment: "Cross-validation is an even better method than a hold-out set for estimating the parameters A and B.in 3-fold CV, the training set is split in 3 parts. Each of  SVM are trained on permutations of 2 out of 3 parts, and the fi are evaluated on remaining 3rd. The union of all three sets of fi can form the training set of the sigmoid(and also can be used to adjust the SVM parameters)."
Above i have quoted from Platt's paper but i dont seem to understand which training set it is talking about. Is it the same training set which i have used to perform 10-fold CV to tune C and Gamma?

Comment: Input parameters:
deci = array of SVM decision values
label = array of booleans: is the example labeled +1?
prior1 = number of positive examples
prior0 = number of negative examples
Outputs:
A, B = parameters of sigmoid

but in the pseudo-code provided in paper states above are input/output parameters to platt. 

Is 'deci' parameter is the output decision score from the libsvmpredict for test data?

 For 'label', corresponding to which example these label are? 

Corresponding to which set, no. of positive and no. of negative example it requires?

Comment: Do we use platt scaling also for the test set (1- partition of each fold) while tuning C and gamma with K-fold CV or is it sufficient only to use platt  with the final test set after training on whole dataset in the end.